# Issue with ggplot2 box plots, separate versus grouped charts

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using ggplot2 to make box plots to compare gene expression for genes A, B, and C in normal tissues versus tumors (about 50 normal and 500 tumor samples). The issue is that when I generate separate box plots of the individual genes, they are a bit different than if I plot all three genes together in one graph.

I'm beginning with the three separate dataframes consisting of a column of numeric expression values and a column of factors identifying tumor or normal sample type.

```
head(geneB)
  geneB   sample_type
1 12.02 Primary Tumor
2 11.94 Primary Tumor
3 11.85 Primary Tumor
4 11.84 Primary Tumor
5 11.82 Primary Tumor
6 11.82 Primary Tumor

ggplot(geneB, aes(x=sample_type, y = geneB))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  labs(title = "Gene B Expression", x= "Gene", y = "Log2 normalized counts")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

The resulting bloxplot for gene B looks like this. Note that the entire box for the gene B tumor group is higher than the median of the normal group, and the tumor median is above the box for the normal group

[image]

Now if I combine the three dataframes together and generate a single chart with box plots for all three genes I get the following chart.

```
genes.df <- cbind(geneA[,1],geneB[,1],geneC)
colnames(genes.df)<-c("geneA","geneB","geneC","sample_type")
genes.df2 <- melt(genes.df, id.vars = "sample_type", variable.name = "Gene", value.name = "Normalized_Counts")
head(genes.df2)
    sample_type  Gene Normalized_Counts
1 Primary Tumor geneA             8.602
2 Primary Tumor geneA             8.545
3 Primary Tumor geneA             8.542
4 Primary Tumor geneA             8.420
5 Primary Tumor geneA             8.397
6 Primary Tumor geneA             8.379
> 
#Combined Boxplot
ggplot(genes.df2, aes(x= Gene, y = Normalized_Counts, fill = sample_type))+ 
  geom_boxplot()+
  labs(title = "Gene Expression", x= "Gene", y = "Log2 normalized counts", fill = NULL)+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

Note that the gene B tumor box now extends below the normal group's median and the tumor median is not above the normal box. There are similar differences when I look closely at gene C graphed separately versus together. From manually examining the data, the separate box plots are the more correct representation of the data.

Anybody have insights or suggestions?  Thanks for your help

Edits:

1. I suppose the issue might actually stem from an error in melting my data instead of a ggplot graphing problem. Will try to look at that more myself this afternoon.
2. the three dataframes are provided below

```
dput(geneA)
structure(list(geneA = c(8.602, 8.545, 8.542, 8.42, 8.397, 8.379, 
8.286, 8.275, 8.213, 8.092, 8.081, 8.08, 8.066, 8.065, 8.061, 
8.054, 8.028, 7.97, 7.966, 7.948, 7.932, 7.922, 7.921, 7.901, 
7.899, 7.899, 7.881, 7.88, 7.878, 7.861, 7.855, 7.845, 7.844, 
7.84, 7.828, 7.822, 7.805, 7.786, 7.779, 7.744, 7.735, 7.725, 
7.715, 7.708, 7.701, 7.698, 7.698, 7.65, 7.648, 7.647, 7.64, 
7.635, 7.619, 7.57, 7.562, 7.539, 7.534, 7.516, 7.48, 7.461, 
7.459, 7.415, 7.401, 7.324, 7.318, 7.296, 7.288, 7.285, 7.266, 
7.266, 7.262, 7.257, 7.249, 7.249, 7.232, 7.23, 7.228, 7.226, 
7.212, 7.211, 7.157, 7.154, 7.142, 7.114, 7.111, 7.102, 7.102, 
7.083, 7.082, 7.076, 7.075, 7.049, 7.036, 7.035, 7.034, 7.006, 
6.988, 6.958, 6.945, 6.943, 6.937, 6.935, 6.926, 6.91, 6.908, 
6.899, 6.886, 6.879, 6.869, 6.857, 6.852, 6.833, 6.81, 6.806, 
6.801, 6.797, 6.781, 6.773, 6.768, 6.766, 6.759, 6.751, 6.744, 
6.741, 6.739, 6.722, 6.721, 6.713, 6.701, 6.678, 6.671, 6.664, 
6.664, 6.657, 6.656, 6.632, 6.63, 6.612, 6.606, 6.606, 6.597, 
6.571, 6.547, 6.547, 6.525, 6.508, 6.492, 6.489, 6.471, 6.465, 
6.464, 6.449, 6.442, 6.437, 6.411, 6.411, 6.406, 6.405, 6.4, 
6.4, 6.398, 6.379, 6.37, 6.325, 6.324, 6.313, 6.308, 6.304, 6.304, 
6.274, 6.271, 6.264, 6.254, 6.254, 6.238, 6.237, 6.225, 6.221, 
6.21, 6.207, 6.203, 6.193, 6.193, 6.19, 6.183, 6.178, 6.151, 
6.148, 6.147, 6.14, 6.132, 6.122, 6.121, 6.111, 6.107, 6.102, 
6.087, 6.08, 6.08, 6.073, 6.056, 6.043, 6.028, 6.026, 6.02, 6.016, 
6.014, 5.994, 5.984, 5.983, 5.965, 5.964, 5.952, 5.949, 5.934, 
5.898, 5.898, 5.894, 5.881, 5.88, 5.853, 5.851, 5.84, 5.822, 
5.82, 5.806, 5.802, 5.793, 5.793, 5.788, 5.782, 5.774, 5.769, 
5.769, 5.759, 5.75, 5.735, 5.731, 5.72, 5.707, 5.701, 5.694, 
5.694, 5.687, 5.687, 5.687, 5.668, 5.667, 5.66, 5.658, 5.647, 
5.637, 5.617, 5.617, 5.614, 5.604, 5.597, 5.572, 5.57, 5.552, 
5.531, 5.526, 5.498, 5.48, 5.479, 5.473, 5.469, 5.464, 5.453, 
5.451, 5.449, 5.449, 5.447, 5.427, 5.42, 5.406, 5.4, 5.394, 5.385, 
5.366, 5.364, 5.361, 5.353, 5.352, 5.349, 5.347, 5.338, 5.336, 
5.335, 5.329, 5.318, 5.3, 5.291, 5.286, 5.283, 5.274, 5.257, 
5.256, 5.255, 5.248, 5.236, 5.229, 5.226, 5.221, 5.206, 5.203, 
5.194, 5.178, 5.167, 5.161, 5.147, 5.141, 5.137, 5.136, 5.12, 
5.118, 5.108, 5.106, 5.103, 5.08, 5.074, 5.065, 5.063, 5.052, 
5.038, 5.034, 5.029, 5.021, 5.015, 5.008, 4.993, 4.988, 4.981, 
4.974, 4.97, 4.968, 4.965, 4.964, 4.956, 4.953, 4.937, 4.922, 
4.921, 4.917, 4.912, 4.901, 4.897, 4.895, 4.876, 4.873, 4.851, 
4.84, 4.839, 4.839, 4.829, 4.828, 4.823, 4.789, 4.788, 4.785, 
4.78, 4.776, 4.753, 4.752, 4.743, 4.729, 4.699, 4.685, 4.682, 
4.663, 4.65, 4.649, 4.645, 4.633, 4.63, 4.592, 4.566, 4.566, 
4.566, 4.544, 4.53, 4.527, 4.524, 4.516, 4.516, 4.509, 4.504, 
4.499, 4.497, 4.496, 4.495, 4.491, 4.489, 4.489, 4.47, 4.465, 
4.462, 4.451, 4.439, 4.437, 4.421, 4.411, 4.4, 4.394, 4.381, 
4.381, 4.379, 4.363, 4.358, 4.344, 4.338, 4.294, 4.267, 4.242, 
4.239, 4.236, 4.229, 4.227, 4.22, 4.214, 4.211, 4.21, 4.208, 
4.198, 4.197, 4.18, 4.177, 4.162, 4.151, 4.145, 4.142, 4.141, 
4.117, 4.108, 4.1, 4.089, 4.084, 4.072, 4.069, 4.054, 4.053, 
4.029, 4.028, 4.023, 4.022, 4.02, 4.017, 4.016, 4.007, 4.002, 
3.993, 3.984, 3.956, 3.945, 3.929, 3.925, 3.923, 3.91, 3.899, 
3.892, 3.891, 3.89, 3.889, 3.868, 3.865, 3.864, 3.863, 3.862, 
3.859, 3.841, 3.841, 3.834, 3.832, 3.805, 3.783, 3.779, 3.745, 
3.744, 3.735, 3.735, 3.702, 3.694, 3.684, 3.683, 3.681, 3.675, 
3.652, 3.638, 3.601, 3.566, 3.557, 3.525, 3.521, 3.512, 3.511, 
3.475, 3.472, 3.444, 3.441, 3.438, 3.434, 3.372, 3.342, 3.337, 
3.323, 3.319, 3.318, 3.306, 3.302, 3.238, 3.238, 3.234, 3.231, 
3.223, 3.211, 3.208, 3.183, 3.179, 3.154, 3.152, 3.144, 3.109, 
3.103, 3.072, 3.069, 3.065, 3.063, 3.052, 3.042, 3.029, 2.987, 
2.952, 2.932, 2.926, 2.917, 2.886, 2.883, 2.864, 2.808, 2.793, 
2.724, 2.717, 2.65, 2.638, 2.598, 2.58, 2.559, 2.531, 2.493, 
2.49, 2.463, 2.455, 2.418, 2.336, 2.332, 2.277, 2.142, 1.957, 
1.58, 1.215, 0.6077, 0, 0, 0), sample_type = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("Solid Tissue Normal", "Primary Tumor"
), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -564L), class = "data.frame")
> dput(geneB)
structure(list(geneB = c(12.02, 11.94, 11.85, 11.84, 11.82, 11.82, 
11.81, 11.76, 11.64, 11.61, 11.55, 11.55, 11.53, 11.52, 11.5, 
11.5, 11.5, 11.48, 11.48, 11.47, 11.46, 11.45, 11.44, 11.44, 
11.42, 11.41, 11.41, 11.4, 11.4, 11.4, 11.39, 11.39, 11.39, 11.38, 
11.38, 11.38, 11.37, 11.34, 11.33, 11.33, 11.32, 11.32, 11.3, 
11.3, 11.3, 11.28, 11.28, 11.27, 11.27, 11.26, 11.26, 11.26, 
11.26, 11.26, 11.26, 11.25, 11.25, 11.25, 11.25, 11.24, 11.24, 
11.23, 11.22, 11.21, 11.21, 11.21, 11.2, 11.19, 11.19, 11.19, 
11.19, 11.18, 11.18, 11.18, 11.18, 11.17, 11.16, 11.16, 11.16, 
11.16, 11.16, 11.16, 11.16, 11.15, 11.15, 11.14, 11.14, 11.13, 
11.12, 11.12, 11.11, 11.11, 11.11, 11.11, 11.11, 11.11, 11.11, 
11.1, 11.09, 11.09, 11.09, 11.09, 11.08, 11.08, 11.07, 11.07, 
11.07, 11.07, 11.06, 11.05, 11.05, 11.05, 11.05, 11.04, 11.04, 
11.04, 11.04, 11.04, 11.04, 11.03, 11.03, 11.03, 11.02, 11.02, 
11.01, 11.01, 11.01, 11.01, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 10.98, 
10.98, 10.98, 10.97, 10.97, 10.97, 10.97, 10.97, 10.97, 10.97, 
10.96, 10.96, 10.96, 10.96, 10.96, 10.96, 10.96, 10.95, 10.95, 
10.95, 10.95, 10.95, 10.95, 10.95, 10.94, 10.94, 10.94, 10.94, 
10.93, 10.93, 10.93, 10.93, 10.93, 10.92, 10.92, 10.92, 10.92, 
10.92, 10.92, 10.92, 10.91, 10.91, 10.91, 10.91, 10.91, 10.91, 
10.91, 10.91, 10.9, 10.9, 10.9, 10.9, 10.9, 10.9, 10.9, 10.89, 
10.89, 10.89, 10.89, 10.89, 10.89, 10.88, 10.88, 10.88, 10.88, 
10.87, 10.87, 10.87, 10.87, 10.87, 10.87, 10.87, 10.86, 10.86, 
10.86, 10.86, 10.86, 10.86, 10.85, 10.85, 10.85, 10.85, 10.85, 
10.84, 10.84, 10.84, 10.84, 10.84, 10.84, 10.83, 10.83, 10.83, 
10.83, 10.83, 10.83, 10.83, 10.82, 10.82, 10.82, 10.82, 10.82, 
10.81, 10.81, 10.81, 10.81, 10.81, 10.81, 10.8, 10.8, 10.79, 
10.79, 10.79, 10.79, 10.79, 10.79, 10.78, 10.78, 10.78, 10.78, 
10.77, 10.77, 10.77, 10.77, 10.77, 10.77, 10.77, 10.77, 10.76, 
10.76, 10.76, 10.75, 10.75, 10.75, 10.75, 10.75, 10.75, 10.74, 
10.74, 10.74, 10.74, 10.74, 10.74, 10.74, 10.74, 10.73, 10.73, 
10.71, 10.71, 10.71, 10.71, 10.71, 10.71, 10.71, 10.71, 10.7, 
10.69, 10.69, 10.69, 10.69, 10.68, 10.68, 10.68, 10.68, 10.68, 
10.68, 10.68, 10.68, 10.68, 10.67, 10.67, 10.67, 10.67, 10.67, 
10.67, 10.67, 10.67, 10.67, 10.66, 10.66, 10.66, 10.66, 10.66, 
10.66, 10.66, 10.66, 10.66, 10.66, 10.65, 10.65, 10.65, 10.65, 
10.65, 10.64, 10.64, 10.64, 10.64, 10.64, 10.63, 10.63, 10.63, 
10.63, 10.63, 10.63, 10.63, 10.62, 10.62, 10.61, 10.61, 10.61, 
10.61, 10.61, 10.61, 10.61, 10.6, 10.6, 10.6, 10.6, 10.6, 10.6, 
10.6, 10.6, 10.6, 10.6, 10.59, 10.59, 10.59, 10.59, 10.58, 10.58, 
10.58, 10.58, 10.58, 10.57, 10.57, 10.57, 10.57, 10.57, 10.57, 
10.56, 10.56, 10.56, 10.56, 10.55, 10.55, 10.55, 10.55, 10.54, 
10.53, 10.53, 10.53, 10.52, 10.52, 10.52, 10.52, 10.51, 10.51, 
10.51, 10.5, 10.5, 10.49, 10.49, 10.49, 10.49, 10.48, 10.48, 
10.48, 10.48, 10.48, 10.47, 10.47, 10.47, 10.47, 10.47, 10.47, 
10.46, 10.46, 10.46, 10.46, 10.46, 10.46, 10.45, 10.45, 10.45, 
10.45, 10.45, 10.45, 10.44, 10.44, 10.44, 10.43, 10.43, 10.43, 
10.43, 10.42, 10.42, 10.42, 10.42, 10.42, 10.41, 10.41, 10.4, 
10.4, 10.4, 10.4, 10.4, 10.39, 10.39, 10.39, 10.38, 10.38, 10.37, 
10.37, 10.37, 10.35, 10.35, 10.35, 10.34, 10.33, 10.33, 10.33, 
10.32, 10.32, 10.3, 10.3, 10.3, 10.29, 10.29, 10.29, 10.29, 10.29, 
10.28, 10.27, 10.27, 10.27, 10.27, 10.27, 10.26, 10.26, 10.26, 
10.26, 10.25, 10.25, 10.25, 10.24, 10.24, 10.23, 10.23, 10.23, 
10.22, 10.22, 10.22, 10.22, 10.21, 10.21, 10.21, 10.2, 10.19, 
10.19, 10.19, 10.19, 10.18, 10.18, 10.18, 10.17, 10.17, 10.16, 
10.16, 10.16, 10.16, 10.16, 10.15, 10.15, 10.13, 10.13, 10.13, 
10.12, 10.11, 10.11, 10.09, 10.09, 10.08, 10.08, 10.07, 10.06, 
10.05, 10.04, 10.04, 10.03, 10.03, 10.02, 10.02, 10.01, 9.999, 
9.976, 9.967, 9.964, 9.955, 9.951, 9.939, 9.939, 9.895, 9.894, 
9.888, 9.882, 9.858, 9.857, 9.815, 9.811, 9.809, 9.79, 9.759, 
9.719, 9.718, 9.677, 9.674, 9.666, 9.651, 9.581, 9.567, 9.536, 
9.508, 9.427, 9.385, 9.343, 9.254, 9.188, 9.03, 8.724), sample_type = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L), levels = c("Solid Tissue Normal", "Primary Tumor"
), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -564L), class = "data.frame")
> dput(geneC)
structure(list(geneC = c(11.24, 11.14, 10.77, 10.75, 10.71, 10.66, 
10.65, 10.65, 10.63, 10.62, 10.62, 10.61, 10.61, 10.59, 10.56, 
10.55, 10.54, 10.53, 10.53, 10.51, 10.5, 10.47, 10.45, 10.44, 
10.44, 10.42, 10.41, 10.4, 10.39, 10.38, 10.38, 10.38, 10.36, 
10.35, 10.35, 10.35, 10.34, 10.34, 10.34, 10.33, 10.33, 10.33, 
10.32, 10.31, 10.31, 10.3, 10.3, 10.3, 10.29, 10.27, 10.25, 10.24, 
10.24, 10.23, 10.23, 10.23, 10.23, 10.22, 10.22, 10.22, 10.22, 
10.21, 10.21, 10.21, 10.2, 10.2, 10.19, 10.19, 10.19, 10.19, 
10.18, 10.17, 10.17, 10.17, 10.16, 10.16, 10.15, 10.15, 10.15, 
10.15, 10.14, 10.13, 10.13, 10.13, 10.12, 10.11, 10.11, 10.11, 
10.1, 10.1, 10.1, 10.09, 10.09, 10.09, 10.09, 10.08, 10.08, 10.08, 
10.08, 10.08, 10.07, 10.07, 10.07, 10.06, 10.05, 10.05, 10.04, 
10.04, 10.04, 10.03, 10.02, 10.02, 10.02, 10.02, 10.01, 10, 10, 
10, 9.993, 9.993, 9.993, 9.991, 9.991, 9.989, 9.988, 9.984, 9.981, 
9.981, 9.977, 9.975, 9.973, 9.973, 9.973, 9.972, 9.971, 9.97, 
9.969, 9.966, 9.965, 9.962, 9.962, 9.96, 9.959, 9.958, 9.954, 
9.946, 9.944, 9.943, 9.941, 9.937, 9.936, 9.935, 9.935, 9.932, 
9.927, 9.925, 9.923, 9.919, 9.913, 9.91, 9.909, 9.908, 9.908, 
9.906, 9.897, 9.896, 9.892, 9.889, 9.888, 9.888, 9.885, 9.885, 
9.884, 9.883, 9.882, 9.874, 9.873, 9.873, 9.872, 9.868, 9.865, 
9.858, 9.856, 9.845, 9.839, 9.835, 9.828, 9.82, 9.81, 9.805, 
9.804, 9.804, 9.798, 9.788, 9.788, 9.787, 9.785, 9.785, 9.784, 
9.783, 9.779, 9.778, 9.774, 9.773, 9.769, 9.768, 9.761, 9.747, 
9.745, 9.745, 9.745, 9.743, 9.742, 9.733, 9.728, 9.728, 9.726, 
9.718, 9.715, 9.714, 9.712, 9.71, 9.709, 9.709, 9.709, 9.703, 
9.703, 9.696, 9.691, 9.688, 9.686, 9.682, 9.681, 9.677, 9.674, 
9.669, 9.668, 9.663, 9.662, 9.657, 9.656, 9.648, 9.647, 9.645, 
9.642, 9.642, 9.642, 9.636, 9.634, 9.63, 9.624, 9.618, 9.614, 
9.614, 9.613, 9.613, 9.611, 9.611, 9.61, 9.595, 9.593, 9.59, 
9.585, 9.584, 9.581, 9.58, 9.575, 9.575, 9.574, 9.571, 9.568, 
9.565, 9.565, 9.564, 9.564, 9.561, 9.558, 9.555, 9.555, 9.554, 
9.549, 9.546, 9.545, 9.541, 9.537, 9.532, 9.531, 9.53, 9.529, 
9.528, 9.521, 9.521, 9.519, 9.519, 9.517, 9.516, 9.516, 9.514, 
9.513, 9.512, 9.511, 9.51, 9.509, 9.508, 9.501, 9.5, 9.497, 9.494, 
9.489, 9.489, 9.486, 9.483, 9.468, 9.463, 9.463, 9.458, 9.457, 
9.454, 9.45, 9.443, 9.442, 9.442, 9.436, 9.432, 9.432, 9.431, 
9.431, 9.429, 9.429, 9.428, 9.426, 9.426, 9.423, 9.423, 9.42, 
9.418, 9.417, 9.41, 9.405, 9.405, 9.402, 9.399, 9.398, 9.395, 
9.393, 9.392, 9.392, 9.39, 9.385, 9.383, 9.377, 9.37, 9.368, 
9.367, 9.364, 9.361, 9.361, 9.36, 9.356, 9.349, 9.342, 9.342, 
9.34, 9.339, 9.338, 9.331, 9.327, 9.326, 9.323, 9.319, 9.319, 
9.312, 9.307, 9.304, 9.303, 9.3, 9.293, 9.292, 9.29, 9.289, 9.283, 
9.271, 9.268, 9.263, 9.257, 9.256, 9.255, 9.255, 9.25, 9.25, 
9.248, 9.246, 9.241, 9.24, 9.239, 9.239, 9.238, 9.237, 9.237, 
9.211, 9.205, 9.203, 9.193, 9.193, 9.193, 9.188, 9.186, 9.182, 
9.181, 9.177, 9.176, 9.173, 9.172, 9.159, 9.158, 9.158, 9.151, 
9.146, 9.135, 9.134, 9.133, 9.133, 9.125, 9.123, 9.116, 9.114, 
9.112, 9.112, 9.097, 9.092, 9.079, 9.079, 9.074, 9.064, 9.057, 
9.053, 9.052, 9.049, 9.035, 9.031, 9.03, 9.026, 9.021, 9.02, 
9.016, 9.012, 9.009, 9.008, 9.007, 8.996, 8.995, 8.991, 8.981, 
8.975, 8.968, 8.965, 8.964, 8.963, 8.938, 8.929, 8.918, 8.918, 
8.914, 8.913, 8.909, 8.908, 8.901, 8.897, 8.895, 8.892, 8.886, 
8.886, 8.88, 8.872, 8.867, 8.866, 8.857, 8.854, 8.85, 8.848, 
8.842, 8.835, 8.83, 8.829, 8.822, 8.814, 8.811, 8.808, 8.794, 
8.792, 8.78, 8.777, 8.771, 8.761, 8.745, 8.745, 8.736, 8.731, 
8.73, 8.728, 8.727, 8.717, 8.714, 8.713, 8.686, 8.68, 8.678, 
8.645, 8.635, 8.614, 8.612, 8.592, 8.588, 8.587, 8.586, 8.58, 
8.575, 8.571, 8.557, 8.549, 8.544, 8.511, 8.498, 8.485, 8.458, 
8.458, 8.453, 8.451, 8.383, 8.347, 8.34, 8.338, 8.333, 8.308, 
8.298, 8.275, 8.261, 8.249, 8.221, 8.212, 8.136, 8.134, 8.13, 
8.093, 8.002, 8.001, 7.995, 7.981, 7.977, 7.97, 7.963, 7.946, 
7.944, 7.938, 7.913, 7.844, 7.84, 7.58, 7.523, 7.518, 7.487, 
7.414, 6.959, 6.212), sample_type = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
), levels = c("Solid Tissue Normal", "Primary Tumor"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-564L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you provide the data from `geneA`, `geneB`, and `geneC` using `dput()`? This will make your code reproducible for others.

Answer (score 0):

Did some data get filtered out? Try adding:

ylim(c('lower limit','upper limit'))

Comment: Please post an answer when you are sure about the result, not when it is a supposition.
Please also take author's code in you answer with you updates.

Your answer could have been a comment (soon unlocked).

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you did not take care of the sample type when `cbind`ing the three datasets, e.g. for row 36 we have  `Solid Tissue Normal` for `geneA` but `Primary Tumor` for B and C.

```r
geneA[36,]
#>    geneA         sample_type
#> 36 7.822 Solid Tissue Normal
geneB[36,]
#>    geneB   sample_type
#> 36 11.38 Primary Tumor
geneC[36,]
#>    geneC   sample_type
#> 36 10.35 Primary Tumor
```

However, when you do `cbind(geneA[,1],geneB[,1],geneC)` all three genes are assigned the sample type from C, i.e. obs 36 for A is assigned `Primary Tumor`.

To fix that I would suggest to row bind your dataset using e.g. `dplyr::bind_rows` where as an intermediate step I first rename the `gene` columns. After doing so everything works fine and the there is no difference between the grouped plot and the separate plots:

```
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
library(ggplot2)

genes.df2 <- dplyr::lst(geneA, geneB, geneC) |> 
  lapply(rename_with, ~"Normalized_Counts", starts_with("gene")) |> 
  bind_rows(.id = "Gene")

ggplot(genes.df2, aes(x= Gene, y = Normalized_Counts, fill = sample_type))+ 
  geom_boxplot()+
  labs(title = "Gene Expression", x= "Gene", y = "Log2 normalized counts", fill = NULL)+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

Comment: Ahhh..given the original source of the data, I'd believed they were in the same order so didn't think to look into that further. I'm just learning ggplot and this was making me pull my hair out!  Nice catch and thank you!